# SCOPE_INDENTITY() not working is it returning null?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, c#-4.0, ado.net

Having read around this site I thought the following code would return the ID of the item  I add to my database but the int value I am trying to fill isn't showing up in scope. Here is the code for my insert statement:

```
  foreach (ExOb exc in exobject)
            {

                Type type = exc.GetType();
                //Add a weight exercise
                if (type == typeof(Weights))
                {

                    Weights thisweight = (Weights)exc;
                    string InsertWeight = ("INSERT INTO WeightExercise (ExcerciseName, Duration, Sets, DiaryId) VALUES (@name, @time, @sets, @DiaryId) SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();");

                        com = new SqlCommand(InsertWeight, con);
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", thisweight.ExcerciseName);
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", thisweight.WeightDuration);
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sets", thisweight.TotalSets);
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DiaryId", results[0]);
                        com.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                        con.Open();
                        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        int ID = (int)com.Parameters["@ID"].Value;

                        con.Close();


                }
                else if (type == typeof(Cardio))
                {
                    Cardio thiscardio = (Cardio)exc;


                }

            }
        }
```

The database is updated with the Weight Exercise details. I have checked when debugging and the command parameter @ID holds the ID of the latest entry. Int ID does not show up in locals when debugging and if I Watch it I get:

```
    ID  The name 'ID' does not exist in the current context
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is this a scoping problem? ID exists only within the if (type == typeof(Weights)) block

Comment: I have done this with just a select scope_identity() but I cannot see what is wrong with your code.

Comment: Is there an `IDENTITY` column here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have checked when debugging and the command parameter @ID holds the
>   ID of the latest entry.

This indicates the database code you are currently using is functioning fine.

> Int ID does not show up in locals when debugging and if I Watch it I
>   get...

This is the root of your question. The problem is that you've scoped ID to inside the

```
if (type == typeof(Weights))
```

block. Outside of that block, the identifier `ID` has no meaning.

Declare `ID` at the top of the scope for this procedure and you should be able to see it in Locals or add a Watch.

Comment: This was it although all other answers very helpful - moving the declaration didn't bring into view in Locals or watch but completing my code and using it to update column in another table did. Thanks and apologies for slightly pointless question!!!

Answer (score 4):

`SCOPE_IDENTITY` returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope. You need to use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery` to retrieve it:

So change your sql first to:

> "INSERT INTO WeightExercise (ExcerciseName, Duration, Sets, DiaryId)
>   VALUES (@name, @time, @sets, @DiaryId); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();"

then you can retrieve the id in this way:

```
ID = (int)com.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: the OP is updating a parameter specified as output - it should have been fine as-was, with executenonquery

Answer (score 0):

I assume that table has an Identity column.

Try doing this:

```
string InsertWeight = ("INSERT INTO WeightExercise 
(ExcerciseName, Duration, Sets, DiaryId) VALUES (@name, @time, @sets, @DiaryId); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()");
```

Then instead of `com.ExecuteNonQuery()` use `int ID = (int) com.ExecuteScalar()`;

To your actual issue, try putting a semicolon after your insert statement and before the SET. The reason is because you are in the same statement. When SCOPE_IDENTITY() gets called, there has not been an insert yet. You need to terminate the statement (`;`) and then call `SCOPE_IDENTITY();`